# Python convert tuple to string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, tuples, data-conversion

I have a tuple of characters like such:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e')
```

How do I convert it to a string so that it is like:

```
'abcdgxre'
```

Comment: Try this also `reduce(add, ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))`

Comment: what is `add` in this exmple @GrijeshChauhan?

Comment: @Steve You need to import `add` function from `operator` module. Btw `"".join` better suits here but if you want to add different types of objects you can use add Check [this working example](http://codepad.org/010AxubW)

Comment: @intel3, How can we remove the tuple outside of the dictionary??```({'entities': [[44, 58, 'VESSEL'], [123, 139, 'VESSEL'], [146, 163, 'COMP'], [285, 292, 'ADDR'], [438, 449, 'ADDR'], [452, 459, 'ADDR']]},)```

Comment: @Pravin Those aren't tuples.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> tup = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e')
>>> ''.join(tup)
'abcdgxre'
>>>
>>> help(str.join)
Help on method_descriptor:

join(...)
    S.join(iterable) -> str

    Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
    iterable.  The separator between elements is S.

>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if tuple contains numbers. Try tup =  (3, None, None, None, None, 1406836313736)

Comment: For numbers you can try this: `''.join(map(str, tup))`

Comment: For Numbers and None please try `''.join(map(lambda x: str(x or ''), (None, 1, 2, 'apple')))`

Answer (score 33):

here is an easy way to use join.

```
''.join(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e'))
```

Answer (score 21):

This works:

```
''.join(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e'))
```

It will produce:

```
'abcdgxre'
```

You can also use a delimiter like a comma to produce:

```
'a,b,c,d,g,x,r,e'
```

By using:

```
','.join(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e'))
```

Comment: Of course it works. It was marked as the accepted answer 5 years before you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If just using `str()` for a tuple as shown below:

```py
t = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e')

print(t, type(t))

s = str(t) # Here

print(s, type(s))
```

Only the type can be changed from `tuple` to `str` without changing the value as shown below:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e') <class 'tuple'>
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'x', 'r', 'e') <class 'str'>
```