# Python from tuples to strings

Tags: python, string, tuples

new to the python programming, havin some difficulties figuring this out. 
I'm trying to convert tuples into strings, for example ('h','e',4) into 'he4'. i've submitted a version using the .join function, and i'm required to come up with another ver. i'm given the following:

```
def filter(pred, seq): # keeps elements that satisfy predicate
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    elif pred(seq[0]):
        return (seq[0],) + filter(pred, seq[1:])
    else:
        return filter(pred, seq[1:])

def accumulate(fn, initial, seq):
    if seq == ():
        return initial
    else:
        return fn(seq[0],  accumulate(fn, initial, seq[1:]))
```

hints on how to use the following to come up with conversion of tuples to strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641579/python-convert-tuple-to-string)

Comment: @BrandonKheang Nothing there uses the above two functions.

Comment: "the following"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given `filter` is useless for this but the given `accumulate` can be used easily:

```
>>> t = ('h','e',4)
>>> accumulate(lambda x, s: str(x) + s, '', t)
'he4'
```

Comment: may i know what does str(x) + s means?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the tuple.

```
#tup stores your tuple
string = ''
for s in tuple :
    string+=s
```

Here you are going through the tuple and adding each element of it into a new string.

Comment: I think the OP is required to use those funny looking functions, otherwise you're right this would be a very simple solution

Comment: Hmmm. Might be. Why complicate it when you can keep it simple I say. But yes, if that's the requirement, will looking into it.

Comment: Though @Davy M , the function the OP provides seems weird. Can you make out what that looks like?

Comment: I really can't haha

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `reduce` function:

```
>>> t = ('h','e',4)
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y), t, '')
'he4'
```

2) Use foolish recursion:

```
>>> def str_by_recursion(t,s=''):
        if not t: return ''
        return str(t[0]) + str_by_recursion(t[1:])

>>> str_by_recursion(t)
'he4'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use map to and join.

```
tup = ('h','e',4)
map_str = map(str, tup)
print(''.join(map_str))
```

Map takes two arguments. First argument is the function which has to be used for each element of the list. Second argument is the iterable.