# Turn a tuple containing letters, numbers, symbols, or tags, into a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, join, tuples, multilinestring

I have found the stackoverflow question:
[Python convert tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641579/python-convert-tuple-to-string) a great source so far, but my list of strings contain "#" and "\n".

(the following example has been shortened for readability.  The actual tuple would create 7 lines when completed)

I would like to turn this tuple:

```
('\n', '0', '#', '0', '0', '0', '0', '#', '\n', '0', '#', '#', '0', '0', '#', '#', '\n')
```

into a multi-line string like this.

```
"""
0#0000#
0##00##
"""
```

The code that seems to make the most sense to me is written in the above mentioned thread by Mohammed, but when tried, the tuple stays exactly the same.

```
''.join(map(str, tup))
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

### edited.  complete code.

```
mylist = [('\n', '0', '#', '0', '0', '0', '0', '#', '\n', '0', '#', '#', '0', '0', '#', '#', '\n', '0', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '\n', '0', '#', '#', '0', '0', '#', '#', '\n', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n')]

tuple = str(mylist).strip('[]')
string = "".join(tuple)
```

with the hopes of it returning:

```
"""
0#0000#
0##00##
0######
0##00##
0000000
"""
```

however, when i print or return the above code, the unjoined tuple is the product.

Comment: What does join return? Are you expecting it to change the tup passed in? Maybe show your [mcve]

Comment: `print(''.join(tup))` works for me

Comment: Just `''.join(your_tuple)` produces your output...

Comment: I have tried the .join() function with no luck.  Perhaps when I downsized my code, I left something out.  I will edit my original post with the complete code.

Comment: You have a list containing a Tuple so `''.join(list[0])` or if the list can contain many tuples `''.join(c for t in list for c in t) `

Comment: Thank you Anthony, I just tried that and again the list prints out as a list with no change.  This is part of a project I am working on in checkio.  Is it possible that the interpreter is the cause of this?

Comment: And now it is working.  Thank you all for your help!!!