# I have a section of code from a text game project that isn't working as expected

Tags: python

I have a section of code which looks like this:

`for l in blah:
       sys.stdout.write(l)
       sys.stdout.flush()
       time.sleep(0.025)`

which adds a slight delay between each character being printed in a print statement, which is assigned to the variable `blah`. However, if there is a variable present in the print statement, so for instance:

`blah = "\n", player_name, ", you must save this land from the virus that has blighted us.\n"`

then the print statement will not print as I wanted it to, but rather as a normal print statement would.

I expected the print statement to be printed as if it were being typed quickly, line by line, but instead, the print statement was printed all at once.

Comment: `"\n", player_name, ", you must save this land from the virus that has blighted us.\n"` is a _tuple_ of three elements, two of which are strings. So, `blah[2]`  is the string `", you must save this land from the virus that has blighted us.\n"`.

Comment: `blah` as you show is a tuple not a string. You could convert it to string with something like what's mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641579/python-convert-tuple-to-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "f-string":

```
blah = f"\n{player_name}, you must save this land from the virus that has blighted us.\n"
```

This allows you to substitute variables that are currently in scope (e.g. `player_name`) directly into the string you're building. If `player_name` was `'Alex'`, then the resulting `blah` would be `"\nAlex, you must..."`

---

What you *were* doing was assigning a `tuple` to `blah`. When you then tried to iterate over it, you got "each element of the tuple", rather than "each character of the string". The built-in `print()` function lets you give an arbitrary number of arguments, and internally that does resolve itself as a tuple, but most functions don't let you do that.