# combining lists items

Tags: python, list, combinations

i have some lists with str(numbers) for example ['8', '0', '9', '5', '7'], ['8', '0', '9', '5', '7']
need to join each element from first list with each element from second list ['88','80','89','85','87','08'...] the number of lists can be up to 100

firstly i think to use itertools.product(), but I didn't manage to implement it

Comment: You said you tried `itertools.product` -- did you `join` the products together?  e.g. `[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(first_list, second_list)]`  If that didn't work, what was missing from the output that you were hoping to get?

Comment: See [Python convert tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19641579/6045800) if you are actually using `product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1, l2 = ['8', '0', '9', '5', '7'], ['8', '0', '9', '5', '7']

import itertools

print([''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(l1, l2)])
```

Comment: if more than 2 lists?

Comment: @артемкостриков See the duplicate

Comment: @артемкостриков nothing changes, you just pass one more list to `product`

Comment: thanks, i already seen it

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
L= ['8', '0', '9', '5', '7']
B=['8', '0', '9', '5', '7'] 
your_list=[i+j for i in L for j in B]
```